# What stress tests should be perform if I want my product to be used in enterprise companies?

Tags: json, overloading, enterprise, stress-testing

My startup has about 3,000 people, we created a tool similar to Box and have been able to sell our product to many other startups in SF. We want to focus now on selling to enterprise companies, what stress tests should we perform to ensure that our product can scale? For example to ensure that an enterprise with 300,000+ employees will not experience problems?

I fear that an enterprise may experience an API overload. Meaning too many files passing at once and triggering a cyber attack. **How can this even happen? Any clue? ** Or an API getting too many API calls and then crashing.

This question has been reworded, I don't feel comfortable sharing or giving away too many details from an experience that actually happened at my company--I want this to remain as confidential as possible, while providing as much context as I can.

We expected a flawless API integration that can handle the traffic from a 300,000 employee company.

Comment: `from a 300,000 employee company` - try to define precisely what (you think) this means technically using real numbers and real metrics - number of API calls per second, file sizes limitations, etc. When you've defined them, then you've got something to load test against. As a startup, I would expect, you'll just scale as you go - you'll improve your application structure (because hardware is easy enough to buy on GCP or AWS) where you see bottle-necks start to appear (latency creeping up, db queries taking too long, etc). You don't go from 0-100 without going through 20, 30, 40, 50, 60...IMO